# Windows server 2008 R2 Active Directory and Windows 10 Pro client

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2

Simple question: is it OK/possible to assign a Windows 10 Pro client machine to Windows Domain (AD) on Windows Server 2008R2 machine?

I have not found any obvious answer - maybe because the answer is simply "*of course it's no problem*" (?) - I just want to be sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will absolutely work just fine.

Comment: While you are correct, I don't think you should answer a question that blatantly should be closed as off topic.

Comment: Please, to avoid being lame next time, I need help with 2 things: 1) Why is this Off-topic? Is it because it should have been placed in SuperUser instead? 2) This question brings me negative votes, I do not want to have it here, but since it has been answered, system discourages me to do so... well... what shall I do? :/ Thank you

Comment: it says: "We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge.

Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?"

(I am not allowed to edit my previous comment, if I were, I would add it there)